# what's the best way to get rid of the \0 at the end of a string literal?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something like

```
strcmp(argv[3], "stdout")
```

however, in the command line I don't want to type

```
stdout\0
```

what's the best way to get rid of the \0 at the end of a string literal?

Thanks!

update:

Thanks guys. I found what's wrong with my code... I should have used

```
strcmp(argv[3], "stdout") == 0
```

Thanks @Nicol Bolas

Comment: The NULL terminator is not used as part of the comparison.  If you did remove it then strcmp wouldn't know when to stop.  Try describing the actual issue you're having.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm trying to do "./a.out stdout". In my code, I did if (strcmp(argv[1], "stdout")) something. It doesn't work. It only works when I do "./a.out stdout\0" in the command line

Comment: I assume, given the `./` part, you're using some form of Linux/Unix shell, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to type "stdout\0" on the command line.  Whichever way your system makes command-line arguments available to your process (it differs by operating system) automatically adds the null character.

As you know, a C-style string is terminated by the null character, which is written in code as '\0'.  If that character weren't at the end of the string, a function such as `strcmp` would keep going well beyond the end of the string, since such a string flouts convention.  Since the terminating null character is the C convention, however, the compiler is smart enough to add the null character to the end of a string literal, and the system is smart enough to add the null character to the command-line arguments stored in the memory of a freshly created process.  If `argc` is greater than 3, and the third argument you type on the command-line for your program is "stdout", the call to `strcmp(argv[3], "stdout")` will return 0 to mean that the two strings match.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to type `\0` in most cases. String literals have a `\0` implicitly appended to them, and the C functions that store string data into character arrays will append a `\0` on the end (which is why the documentation for many of those functions specifies that your character buffer must have enough space for the string and the null terminator).

Answer (score 2):

A string literal consists of zero or more characters from the source character set surrounded by double quotation marks ("). A string literal represents a sequence of characters that, taken together, form a null-terminated string.

[strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp)  starts comparing the first character of each string. If they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs until the characters differ or until a terminating null-character is reached.

so you don' t need to write `\0` in the end of `stdout`, you need to compare the return value of `strcmp` to `0`:

```
if (strcmp(argv[3], "stdout") == 0)
```